# parsing information within HTML tags avoiding title value

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to parse the information between HTML tag. Using regular expression, how can I avoid title value as they are different and parse the information within tags only?

HTML code:

```
<p class=period>
<abbr class=dtstart title=2010>2010</abbr>
<abbr class=dtend title=2012>2012</abbr> 
</p>
```

The out put should be something like: 2010, 2012

I am using this method and its working fine, if title=2010:

```
$experience .= "<c:start_date>". trim($this->parse_text($tmp3[$i], "<abbr class=\"dtstart\" title=\"2010\">", "</abbr>"))."</c:start_date>\r\n";
```

I have tried this: `title=\"(.*)\"` but its not working! any suggestion on which regular expression I should use instead?

Many thanks

Comment: How is `parse_text()` defined?

Comment: the regular expression is title=(\d+)

Comment: parse_text function:`function parse_text($str, $start, $end)
 {
    if(empty($str))
    {
       return;
    }
    $pos_start = strpos($str, $start);
    $pos_end = strpos($str, $end, ($pos_start + strlen($start)));
    if ( ($pos_start !== false) && ($pos_end !== false) )
    {
       $pos1 = $pos_start + strlen($start);
       $pos2 = $pos_end - $pos1;
       return substr($str, $pos1, $pos2);
    }
    else return;
 }`

Comment: It's worth to note that there's no regular expression use in `parse_text()` function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions were not designed for HTML parsing. You better using DOM/XPath:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<p class=period>
<abbr class=dtstart title=2010>2010</abbr>
<abbr class=dtend title=2012>2012</abbr> 
</p>
HTML;
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$dtstart = $xpath->query("//abbr[contains(@class, 'dtstart')]")->item(0)->nodeValue;
$dtend = $xpath->query("//abbr[contains(@class, 'dtend')]")->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

To fetch both `dtstart` and `dtend` in one array...

```
$dates = $xpath->query("//abbr[contains(@class, 'dtstart') or contains(@class, 'dtend')]");
list($dtstart, $dtend) = array_map(function ($node) {
    return $node->nodeValue;
}, iterator_to_array($dates));
```